# How to display different messages when clicking on two different radio button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons as shown below :

```
<input type="radio" name="country" value="India" class="website">India
<input type="radio" name="country" value="UAE" class="website">UAE
```

I have written the jquery for this :

```
 $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
        var selection=$(this).val();
        alert("Radio button selection changed. Selected: "+selection);
    });
```

But this is only working when the first radio button is clicked. It wont work when the second radio button is clicked.

Can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: It does work,  please tell me what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: is that your actual html?

Comment: Your code works just fine. It shows `India` and `UAE` when selected.

Comment: second radio button is inactive...

Comment: what do you mean by "inactive"? Could you provide a screenshot or additional information?

Comment: inactive form elements don't accept click events

Answer (score 0):

When a form element is disabled you cannot trigger click events on the element. However, you can put a non-form element such as a `span` around each input and add the click event to the `span` if you would like.

**Note:** Using a label calls the click twice which is why I didn't use it.

```js
$("span").click(function() {
  var selection = $(this).children().first().val();
  alert("Radio button selection changed. Selected: " + selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><input type="radio" name="country" value="India" class="website">India</span>
<span><input type="radio" name="country" value="UAE" class="website" disabled="disabled">UAE</span>
```

Comment: in this code snippet,when UAE radio button, the message inside alert is not working  ..y is it like that ?

Comment: y have u given disabled ?

Comment: You said the element was disabled in the comments.

Comment: When I am clicking the radio button,it is inactive not disabled in code

Comment: Inactive/disabled is the same thing.